# What is the exact parameter?

Tags: javascript

The example from a book (not the whole one, if needed I will provide more).

```
function CSVReader(separators) {
  this.separators = separators || [","];
  this.regexp =
    new RegExp(this.separators.map(function(sep) {
      return "\\" + sep[0];
    }).join("|"));
}
```

What is the `sep` parameter in function?

How do I get its value, when I don't see it declared anywhere?

Comment: Apparently `separators` is supposed to be an array of separator characters (probably for elements of each CSV line), so the `.map()` call iterates through each of those, and that's where `sep` comes from.

Comment: `sep` is each element from `this.separators` and iterated by using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...when I don`t see it declared anywhere?

It's declared in the callback's parameter list...

```
function CSVReader(separators){
this.separators = separators || [","];
this.regexp =
    new RegExp(this.separators.map(function(sep){
// -----------------------------------------^^^^ ---------------------- here
                                                return "\\"+sep[0];
                                            }).join("|"));
}
```

The [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function will call that callback for each entry in the `this.separators` array. In each call, the `sep` parameter receives the value for that entry.

Leaving out a lot of details, `map` basically looks like this:

```
function map(callback) {
    // Here, `this` is the array `map` was called on
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
        result.push(callback(this[i], i, this));
    }
}
```

(One of the main details I left out for clarity is `forEach`'s `thisArg` and calling `callback` with a specific `this` value.)

The callback receives three arguments, but the one in your example only uses one of the (`sep`).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52677933/157247) about `forEach`.

---

FWIW: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript) is a good resource for JavaScript information (and HTML and CSS).

Comment: Ok,thanx, one more question. If .map() takes elements from array one by one, and the function is executed on them, why do I have sep[0]? It is as if an array was passed to sep from an array ?

Comment: @Yozex - The entries in the array are strings. Apparently the author of the code wanted to allow only one-character separators, but didn't want to enforce that with a validation. `sep[0]` when `sep` is `","` is `","`, but `sep[0]` when `sep` is `"xx"` is just `"x"`. A better implementation would check `this.separators` for any entries with `.length` greater than 1 and throw an error, rather than just disregarding subsequent characters in the separators.

Answer (score 3):

`sep` is the individual array element that `map` provides when it iterates over the array.

Learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map